Mathcal not working properly
I wrote the following code
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=scriptsize, labelfont=bf, labelsep=period}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\mbeq}{\overset{!}{=}}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{yhmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/yhmath
\usepackage{mathdots}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathdots
\usepackage{MnSymbol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol
\usepackage{tcolorbox}






\begin{document}
     $\mathds{1}$.
\begin{equation}
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathcal{V}}}\mathbf{\epsilon}_{\lambda\textbf{k}}(\mathbf{k})e^{i\mathbf{k}\mathbf{r}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}

However, V is being compiled as \mathbf{V} on Overleaf.
Interesting enough, if I delete the last part and write only
\begin{document}
     $\mathds{1}$.
\begin{equation}
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathcal{V}}}\mathbf{\epsilon}_{\lambda\textbf{k}}
\end{equation}



mathcal works properly. Is it a bug? Or is there any solution?

No problem here, provided I remove the blank lines inside equation. Aside, note that \textbf{k} should be \mathbf{k}. Please add a minimal example, starting from \documentclass up to \end{document}, that reproduces the issue.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

\mathcal will select whatever font you have specified it should use but as you have shown no code we can not say if there is a bug or not.

unrelated but use \mathbf not \textbf in those expressions.

Note you can not have a blank line in equation so if your real document has blank lines as you show, you will get errors and incorrect output is expected.

I made your fragments into a document they give this output which looks OK to me, please edit the example to show a bad V

I edited the document, such that it now shows the bug. However, I didn’t notice before the textbf{} inside the math mode. I changed it as suggested by egreg and it worked.

You're using too many math font packages. Start by removing gensymb and MnSymbol (the latter will change all math symbols to shapes incompatible with your main font). Do you really need yhmath?

I can reproduce the issue with much less packages: here I only keep the packages that have to do with math fonts.
\documentclass[fleqn,leqno]{article}

\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{yhmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/yhmath
\usepackage{MnSymbol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol

\begin{document}

$\mathds{1}$.
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathcal{V}}}
  \epsilon_{\lambda\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{k})e^{i\mathbf{k}\mathbf{r}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}


I used just \epsilon because \mathbf{\epsilon} does nothing to the letter (but it's not the point) and fixed the single \textbf{k} into \mathbf{k}. The fleqn and leqno options are just to make the picture smaller.
You can check that removing \mathds{1} the issue doesn't show:

but this is just sweeping the problem under the carpet.
General rule Don't load packages you don't know about.
TeX has a limited supply of math groups and you're using too many of them. Some work has been done in order to overcome this limit, but it's better not to stretch. Some advice:

gensymb provides a few symbols that are available elsewhere;
if you load \mathds just for the (horrible) double stroked 1, you waste a symbol font (see later);
mathrsfs uses up a math group as soon as \mathscr is executed once; do you really need it?
MnSymbol provides a wealth of strange symbols, at the expense of changing all math symbols to shapes incompatible with the main font of your document.

So let's start reducing.
\documentclass[fleqn,leqno]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{mathrsfs}% do you really need it?
%\usepackage{yhmath}% do you really need it?
%\usepackage{MnSymbol}% it changes ALL math symbols

\NewDocumentCommand{\bbone}{}{\mathord{\text{\usefont{U}{dsrom}{m}{n}1}}}

\begin{document}

$\bbone$
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathcal{V}}}
  \epsilon_{\lambda\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{k})e^{i\mathbf{k}\mathbf{r}}
\end{equation}in 

\end{document}


Please, review also the other packages you load. You should also be aware that hyperref has to be loaded last (with a few exceptions that aren't in the packages you're loading).

So there is no error about too many math alphabets any more?

@campa Much less than in the past, but stretching the limit might show up in bizarre output. Frank is still working on the issue.

Good to know. I clearly have no problem for my own documents, but when putting stuff together from other co-authors, not having an explicit error message but scrambled output I might miss sounds like a nightmare...
